# copying data from one table to another table

Tags: oracle11g

MY tables

table name:emp

```
Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------ -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------              NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
EMP_NAME                                VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                  
ADDRESS                                 VARCHAR2(15)                                                                                                                                                                                  
PH_NO                                   NUMBER(10)                                                                                                                                                                                    
DPT_NO                                  NUMBER
```

result:

```
1   ram ctr 8892939927  100
2   mohan   ptr 7569936347  101
3   mallu   ppt 9553438342  102
4   scoot   dmc 9874563210  103
5   jim plr 9236548875  104
6   ravi    tpt 8562398756  105
7   manju   hyd 7562398742  106
8   manoj   hyd 869523654   107
9   sarath  ctr 9632158769  108
10  hemanth mpk 9632147852  109
```

table anme: emp_department

```
Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------ -------- -------------------------------------------------------------
EMP_NO                                  NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
DPT_NO                                  NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
PERIOD                                  VARCHAR2(10)
```

now how to exatract(copy) emp_no and dpt_no values to emp_ department

Comment: You already have `emp_no` and `dpt_no` in `emp_department` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean you want to populate `emp_department` from the data in the `emp` table - hopefully so the `dpt_no` column in that table can be removed. You haven't shown the `emp_no` column in `emp`, but it was in your earlier questions so I assume that's a typo. Your data model still seems a bit strange.

So to insert values from another table:

```
insert into emp_department (emp_no, dpt_no)
select emp_no, dpt_no
from emp;
```

You seem to be asking vey basic questions without showing much research. Please read the documentation or at least some tutorials and show what you've tried and what specific problems you're having.

Comment: then how to insert into period

Comment: then how to insert into period

Comment: @ChocolateRam - what value should go in the `period` column? I don't know what that represents. It seems like it would be more normal to have a start date and end date for the employees assignment to a department, rather than a period which would have to keep being adjusted for their current (open-ended) assignment?